# JQUERYUI: Modal buttons dont work when I close and open

Tags: jquery-ui

I am creating a dialog in javascript and for some reason when I first open the dialog the buttons works fine. But when I close and open it the buttons dont work. The edit click function doesnt work the second time when I repopen the dialog

```
   var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));     
   $(newDiv).dialog({
  title: "New Dialog",
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: true,
  width: 650,
  height: 440,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: true,
  buttons: [ 
        {
            html: "<b>Edit</font></b>",
            icons:  {
                        primary: "ui-icon-check"
                    },
            click: function() {

                        $('#notetext').prop("disabled", false);
                        $('#uibtnSubmit').button("enable");

                           //$('#uibtnSubmit').prop("disabled", false);

                           //$("#uibtnSubmit").button().attr('disabled', false).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        }},
            {
            html: "<b><font color='green'>Submit</font></b>",
            disabled:true,
            id: "uibtnSubmit",
            icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-script"                                    
                    },                                
            click: function() {
                        var editnotes = $('#notetext').val();
                        //update the notes in the database against the user. 
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            cache: false,
                            async: false,
                            url:"url",
                            datatype: "json",
                            data: data,
                            success: function(data){
                                $(newDiv).dialog('close');
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, statusText, err){
                                //console.log(err);
                            }
                        });

                    }},
            {
            html: "<b><font color='red'>Exit</font></b>",
            icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-cancel"
                    },
            click: function() {        
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }

            }

    ]

});
```

I tried to use different properties like removeClass, attr but they arent working.

Comment: Tested current code and it runs. There is no way to properly test your issue. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by reloading the page once Exit or submit value was clicked. That way when the dialog box was reloaded it was initialized.